# Best way to implement administration

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, crud

We are a team doing a project at a University and we are creating a web application for which we have decided to use Java Play framework.

One of the next requirements was that the application should have administration capabilities, i.e the client should be able to easily manage users - delete, modify, add them etc.

However, based on my research, it seems what I need is CRUD, which seems to be missing from the Java Play 2.4.x. I have tried cato and play-2-crud, both of which do not seem to work since I assume they are outdated.

We are using the h2 database, and h2-browser seems to allow us to access lots of the data. However, for that we need to stop the application and that will not work.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: CRUD is just a concept of the basic operations needed to persist your data. You can implement it e.g. with Ebean or JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: Agree with Kris, CRUD is just a concept. Play framework has no auto templates for CRUD, you must implement it by yourself (templates and DAOs)